# Php array_intersect output

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

i'm having trouble with how array works.

```
$a = array("24","33","12");
$b = array("24","12");

$c = array_intersect($a,$b);

echo json_encode($c);

// {"0":"24","2":"12"}
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
// ["24","12"]
```

How can i achieve that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(array_values($c));

output

["24","12"]
```

Answer (score 1):

array_intersect  Computes the intersection of arrays

```
<?php

$array1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
var_dump(array_intersect($array2, $array1));

?>
```

will yield

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> int(2)
  [1]=> int(4)
  [2]=> int(6)
}

array(3) {
  [1]=> int(2)
  [3]=> int(4)
  [5]=> int(6)
}
```

. `json_encode` returns string containing the JSON representation of value. For example

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

will output

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

As mamta answered you can use `array_values` to return all the values of an array and json_encode it like 
echo `json_encode(array_values($c))`

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the info.